# Null value in Model property using HiddenFor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I am writing some javascript where the selected option in a dropdown menu get assigned to a hiddenfor value. This hiddenfor is using a model property (SelectedModule).

When I click my submit button, the model.SelectedModule has null value even though I assigned a value to it with my javascript.

**View**

```
@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditUser";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div id="edit-user">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit user details</legend>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.salutation, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Mr", Value = "Mr" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Mrs", Value = "Mrs" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Miss", Value = "Miss" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Ms", Value = "Ms" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Dr", Value = "Dr" }
                     })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.salutation)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstname)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastname)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastname)
            </div>
            @{Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_AutocompleteGroupName.cshtml", this.ViewData);}
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.isactive)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.isactive)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.isactive)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Is approved")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.IsApproved)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.IsApproved)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Maximum concurrent users")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.MaxConcurrentUsers)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.MaxConcurrentUsers)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rowtype)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.rowtype, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "txtNonEditableRowType" })
                - Non editable
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Current Module")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.module_name, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "txtNonEditableModule" })
                - Non editable
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.module_name)
            </div>
            <br />
            @if (Model.rowtype == "ALF")
            {
                <div id="alfModules">
                    @Html.Label("New module")
                    <br />
                    @{Html.RenderAction("_CreateUserModulesAlf", "UserManager");}
                </div>
            }
            @if (Model.rowtype == "BRAD")
            {
                <div id="bradModules">
                    @Html.Label("New module")
                    <br />
                    @{Html.RenderAction("_CreateUserModulesBrad", "UserManager");}
                </div>
            }
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.group_name)
            </div>
            @* <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.group_name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.group_name)
            </div>*@
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Current Group")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.group_name, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "txtNonEditableGroup" })
                - Non editable
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.group_name)
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.selected_module, new { id = "hdnSelectedModule" })
@*            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.selected_moduleAlf, new { id = "hdnSelectedModuleAlf" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.selected_moduleBrad, new { id = "hdnSelectedModuleBrad" })*@
            <br />
            <fieldset style="width: 400px; padding-left: 15px;">
                <legend>Group Checker</legend>
                <div id="createuser-groupnamesearch">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("_txtGroupSearchForm", "UserManager");}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="newModule()" />
            </p>
            <br />
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to User Manager Dashboard", "Index")
        </fieldset>
    </div>




}
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#group_name").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName", "UserManager")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    value: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        //                            alert(item.group);
                        return {
                            label: item.group,
                            value: item.group
                        } // end of return

                    })); // end of response

                }, // end of success
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                } // end of error
            }); // end of ajax
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) { // Assign to hidden values to trigger onchange ajax call.

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GroupnameCheck", "UserManager")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    value: ui.item.label
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        if (index == "AlfGroup") {
                            $("#txtGroupnameExistsAlf").val(value);
                            if ($("#txtGroupnameExistsAlf").val() == "Alf Group doesn't exist.") {
                                $("#txtGroupnameExistsAlf").css("background-color", "red");
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#txtGroupnameExistsAlf').css("background-color", "#33ff00");
                            }
                        }

                        if (index == "BradGroup") {
                            $("#txtGroupnameExistsBrad").val(value);
                            if ($("#txtGroupnameExistsBrad").val() == "Brad Group doesn't exist.") {
                                $("#txtGroupnameExistsBrad").css("background-color", "red");
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#txtGroupnameExistsBrad').css("background-color", "#33ff00");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, // end of success
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                } // end of error
            }); // end of ajax

            $('#hdnGroupAlf').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#hdnGroupBrad').val(ui.item.label);
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }
    });

    function chkSelection() {
        var rowType = $("#txtNonEditableRowType").val();
        if (rowType == "ALF") {

            var selectedVal = $("#ddlSelectedAlf option:selected").val();
            $('#hdnSelectedModule').val(selectedVal);
        }
        else {

            var selectedVal = $("#ddlSelectedBrad option:selected").val();
            $('#hdnSelectedModule').text(selectedVal);
            alert(selectedVal);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Non editable fields grey
        $("#txtNonEditableGroup").css("background-color", "gray");
        $("#txtNonEditableModule").css("background-color", "gray");
        $("#txtNonEditableRowType").css("background-color", "gray");

        // Show/Hide group check part based on IF ALF or BRAD
        var rowType = $("#txtNonEditableRowType").val();

        if (rowType == "ALF") {
            $("#groupname-checker-alf").show();
            $("#groupname-checker-brad").hide();

            var selectedVal = $("txtNonEditableRowType").val();
            $('#hdnModuleAlf').val(selectedVal);

        }
        else {
            $("#groupname-checker-alf").hide();
            $("#groupname-checker-brad").show();

            var selectedVal = $("txtNonEditableRowType").val();
            $('#hdnModuleBrad').val(selectedVal);
        }

    });



    function newModule() { // Assign new selected module from dropdown to hidden form
        // so it can be used in model as selected_module
        if ($("#txtNonEditableRowType").val() == "ALF") {
            var val = $("#module_name :selected").val();
            $("#hdnSelectedModule").val(val);
        }
        else {
            var val = $("#module_name :selected").val();
            $("#hdnSelectedModule").val(val);
        }
    }  
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditUser(vw_UserManager_Model model)
{
    List<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model> modellist = new List<vw_UserManager_Model>();
    int outcome = 0;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        outcome = UserManager.DAL.EditUser(model);
        modellist.Add(model);
    }

    if (outcome == 1)
    {

        if (modellist.FirstOrDefault().rowtype == "Alf")
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return RedirectToAction("showSuccessUser", new
        {
            CrudType = "Edit",
            UserName = modellist.FirstOrDefault().UserName,
            Password = modellist.FirstOrDefault().password,
            FirstName = modellist.FirstOrDefault().firstname,
            LastName = modellist.FirstOrDefault().lastname,
            Email = modellist.FirstOrDefault().email,
            GroupName = modellist.FirstOrDefault().group_name,
            IsActive = modellist.FirstOrDefault().isactive,
            selected_module = modellist.FirstOrDefault().module_name
        });
    }

    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Failure";
        return RedirectToAction("showError", model);
    }
}
```

**Summary**

When an item is selected in the drop down menu, the value is assigned to HiddenFor field. This works from using firebug I can see the value.

The problem is when I submit the form, the model.SelectedModule property in my C# code has a null value.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is your HidderFor inside your `Form`? Have you checked the POST request in FireBug how is it look like? Has the request includes the correct value for `selected_module`?

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you provided, since we have no idea what your logic of testing for ALF is, or how your form is declared, or any number of other things that would help in solving your problem.  However, `$('#hdnSelectedModule').text(selectedVal)` should be `val()` not `text()`

Comment: @MystereMan I will update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the problem but in one of your cases you are doing:

```
$('#hdnSelectedModule').text(selectedVal);
```

which should be:

```
$('#hdnSelectedModule').val(selectedVal);
```

Also since you are already using FireBug, inspect the AJAX request in the `Net` tab. You will see all the key/value pairs that are sent to the server and will be able to more easily identify the problem. For example is there a `SelectedModule=some_value` in the request? If so, assuming that your model has a property called `SelectedModule` and is of simple type (such as string) you will be able to get its value.

Comment: I inspected the URL posted to the server and it doesn't contain that model property. Not quite sure what to do.

Comment: If you are POSTing you cannot expect this value to be in the URL. It will be in the body of the POST request that you could inspect with FireBug. And if the `SelectedModule` is not part of the POST request, then I guess the reason for this is thaht you never included it. For example I can nowhere see such parameter in your `data` AJAX options being sent to the server. Maybe that's why it doesn't get sent. It's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: Changing the jQuery function from text to val worked. I also tidied up my code quite a bit because it was confusing. Thanks!